# NSString draw(in: rect) method changes rect by itself

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring

I am trying to draw a string in a UIView.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let anotheR: anotherView = anotherView(frame: view.bounds)
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    view.addSubview(anotheR)
    anotheR.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    anotheR.draw(CGRect(x: 100, y: 300, width: 50, height: 10))

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}

class anotherView: UIView {

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let suprect = rect
 var string = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s." as NSString
    string.draw(in: rect, withAttributes:  [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24)])

}
}
```

So there is a view and I overrode UIViews function draw(in:) to write a string in a view. So it writes a string but not it specified rectangle (CGRect(x: 100, y: 300, width: 50, height: 10)) . It just draw it in CGrect(x:0,y:0,width: frame.width, height: frame.height). So it changes rect by itself during runtime.

Here it is:
1) programm begins to call  *anotheR.draw(CGRect(x: 100, y: 300, width: 50, height: 10))* method. 
 [image]

2) CGRect somehow changes to CGRect(x:0,y:0,width: frame.width, height: frame.height) [image]
Please maybe someone knows whats happen? It exposed all code I had wrote. Thank you!

Comment: Please [learn how drawing works (Paragraph The Drawing Cycle)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview). You **must not** call `drawRect` by yourself. It's called by the framework when the view is marked to be redrawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually drawRect captures the frame of the view and draws according to it's dimensions , you should not call it explicitly , You only need to specify this line

```
 let anotheR: anotherView = anotherView(frame: view.bounds)
```

Or change it to

```
 let anotheR: anotherView = anotherView(frame:CGRect(x: 100, y: 300, width: 50, height: 10))
```

Also give it a suitable width and height 50 , 10 respectively are not sufficient to display such long text

Answer (score 1):

The solution from SK_khan is correct. In case if you like to keep your **anotherView** bound same with controller view bound, you can choose to set the **CGRect** hard value inside your draw method like this.

```
string.draw(in: CGRect(x: 100, y: 300, width: 50, height: 10), withAttributes:  [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24)])
```